# Socket.io and Express 3.2.6 : Object #<Server> has no method 'connect'

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I see that many peoples have problem like mine but I don't find an answer.
I use Express 3.2.6 and I want to add Socket.io.

**Server side :**

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
 */
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , index = require('./routes/index')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , nunjucks = require('nunjucks')
 , mongoose = require('mongoose')
, validator = require('validator');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'nunjucks');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var socket = io.connect();
```

I think that I make a lot of mistakes.
But I do not understant why node send me that :

```
var socket = io.connect();
                ^
TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'connect'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Damien\workspace\project\app.js:35:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

**UPDATE**
I changed for express.io
http://express-io.org/

But I have a problem. I have no error message but my server and my client do
not seem to communicate.

Client part :

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onload = function(){
    var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8080");

    //Emit ready event.
    socket.emit('ready'); 

    //Listen for the talk event.
    socket.on('talk', function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    });  
};

</script>
```

Server part :

```
var app = require('express.io')()
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks')
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var validator = require('validator'); 

var routes = require('./routes')
var index = require('./routes/index')

app.http().io()

app.set('view engine', 'nunjucks');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

mongoose.connect( '' );

nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});


var urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      long : String,
      count : Number
      }
);

//create model
var urlModel = mongoose.model('urls', urlSchema);



app.get('/', index.index);


//Setup the ready route, and emit talk event.
app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
    req.io.emit('talk', {
        message: 'io event from an io route on the server'
    })
})



app.listen(8080);
```

I do not understand who there is nothing in client console.

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764346/socket-io-error-listen-method-expects-an-http-server-instance-after-moving

Comment: Ok. Something I do not understand. Can I use the same port for http and socket ?

Comment: You should upgrade Express to version 4.

Comment: I changed to express.io but server and client do not want to communicate. (main message edited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem :

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Must be

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```